# Search for multiple strings (from a file) in another file and list the missing strings

Tags: string, bash, file, search

I have a file with 200 student names. Another huge file that contains data for those 200 students. I want to make sure that none of the student names got missed. I'm looking for a script that look at the string from students.txt and then search for it in alldata.txt. If it is missing, list it

I tried using

```
find /tmp/alldata.txt -type f -exec grep -iHFf students.txt {} +
```

But it lists all the matches and misses to provide the list of the strings that it didn't find in the alldata.txt

Comment: Extract all the student names from the second file. Sort both files. Then use the `comm` command to find all the lines in the first file that are missing from the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `find` if you're just searching one file. But if your data file is unstructured text and the names can appear anywhere, you may need to look for them one at a time:

```
while read name; do
  fgrep -q $name alldata.txt || echo $name
done < students.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the student names are in the first field of `alldata.txt`:

```
comm -23 <(sort students.txt) <(awk '{print $1}' alldata.txt | sort -u)
```

`comm -23` prints all the lines that are in the first file but not in the second file. This uses process substitution to treat the output of the two commands as files.